# python ggplot Error message ImportError: cannot import name 'TimeSeries' '

Tags: python, anaconda, importerror, python-ggplot

I am using Anaconda with Windows 7. I have installed with  'pip install pandas' ' pip install ggplot' . But when I 'import ggplot' , I have got the error message 
' ImportError: cannot import name 'TimeSeries' '

Comment: do `conda install scipy` solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the packages from here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/